# Cannot boot due to nfs and gnome display manager

Tags: boot, gnome, mount, nfs

I recently updated to 22.04.3 and I'm having problems booting. The first error message I get is Failed to mount /mnt/nfs
This is followed by dependency failed for remote file system. Finally, failed to start gnome display manager.

The system resides on a laptop that has a bunch of docker containers on it. I have tried the conventional fixes by googling the subject, but nothing seems to work. I have tried a trove of solutions but it doesn't look like I'm making headway, and in fact might be making it worse. The gnome display manager error wasn't part of the original problem.
I am a complete novice when it comes to Ubuntu, so please don't assume I know anything. Thank you all very much for your time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

Read `man 8 mount;man fstab`, and add the `_netdev` option to the line in `/etc/fstab` to delay mounting. From `man 8 mount`:

```
_netdev
              The  filesystem  resides  on a device that requires network access (used to prevent
              the system from attempting to mount these filesystems until the  network  has  been
              enabled on the system).
```